# All combination for creating a fruit basket from given oranges and apples

Tags: algorithm, math, combinations

Say you are given `A` oranges and `B` apples.  You want to create a basket of total `N` fruits. What is the total number of combination of apples and oranges you can make?
Assuming `A+B >= N`.

**Example:**
I have 6 oranges and 6 apples and I want to create a basket with total 9 fruits.
So I have 4 different combinations:

```
3 apples 6 oranges
4 apples 5 oranges
5 apples 4 oranges
6 apples 3 oranges
```

I want to create a simple (and efficient) algorithm to calculate this number.
Is there any mathematical / combinatoric way to calculate this number in O(1)? I couldn't find a correct formula for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer will show a generic way how to get to the correct closed formula, rather than give "here, it works" formula.

To get to a close formula, using the [Stars and Bars formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) and [Inclusion Exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), you want to find the number of solutions to the equation:

```
x1 + x2 = n
s.t.
(1) 0 <= x1 <= A
(2) 0 <= x2 <= B
```

Denote:

```
W(0) = #solutions to the problem regardless of restrictions
W(1) = #solutions to the problem with (1) is NOT correct (x1 > A)
W(2) = #solutions to the problem with (2) is NOT correct (x2 > B)
W(1,2) = #solutions to the problem with both (1,2) NOT correct (x1 > A and X2 > B)
```

From inclusion exclusion principle, the answer to the problem we formalized above is:

```
E = W(0) - (W(1) + W(2)) + W(1,2)
```

All is left is to give formulas to `W(...)`, and for this we will use the Stars and Bars.

Using the equations without constraits and Theorem 2 of bars and stars:

```
W(0) = Choose(N + 2 - 1, 2 - 1) = Choose(N + 1, 1) = N + 1
```

To calculate W(1) and W(2), we force `x1/x2` to be `A+1` or `B+1`, and then go as usual, and get the equations:

```
x1 + x2 = N - A - 1
x1 + x2 = N - B - 1
```

and the number of solutions are (again using theorem 2):

```
W(1) = Choose(N - A - 1 + 2 - 1, 1) = Chose(N-A,1) = max{N-A,0}
W(2) = (similarly) = max{N-B,0}
```

For W(1,2) we set both and go on and get:

```
W(1,2) = Choose(N - A - 1 - B -1 + 2 - 1) = Choose(N-A-B-1,1) = max{N-A-B-1,0}
```

Summing it all together to the **final formula**:

```
E = W(0) - (W(1) + W(2)) + W(1,2) = 
  = N + 1 - max{N-A,0} - max{N-B,0} + max{N-A-B-1,0}
```

Which in your example is:

```
E = 9 + 1 - 3 - 3 + 0 = 4
```

Comment: This is a great explanation, and seems to work for every example I've tried. You just need to fix the typo in the final formula where it's calculating W(2) on max{N-A,0} instead of max{N-B,0}.

Comment: @BrianStephens Thanks, was doing it as you typed your comment.

Comment: Thank you so much for this correct and well explained solution. I wouldn't thought of using Inclusion Exclusion. Guess I need to refresh my memory about combinatorics.

Answer (score 2):

Lets say `A_max` is the maximum of number of `A` that can be included in the combination, and `A_min` be the least number of `A` that must be included in any combination. Then there will be two conditions that must be satisified:

1. `A_max + B_min = N`
2. `A_min + B_max = N`

Since we know `A_max`(which is `min(NumOfA, N)`), `B_min` can be found easily from first equation. Similarly one can find `A_min` from second equation.
Consequently, the list of combinations would be:

`A_max + B_min`

`(A_max-1) + (B_min+1)`

`(A_max-2) + (B_min+2)`

...

`(A_min) + (B_max)`

So the count of such combinations would be `(A_max - A_min + 1)` or `(B_max - B_min + 1)`

Answer (score -1):

It should be

```
   ans = (A + B) - N + 1
```

Comment: No. Take for example total of 4 fruits. and you have 10 apples and 1 orange. The total number of combinations is 2. Either 1 orange and 3 apples or 0 oranges and 4 apples. Copied comment from another answer.

Comment: Sorry My mistake.

Comment: I have copied the comment of author from another answer which is not satisfying the same. Your answer won't give correct input if ```A``` is 10 ```B``` is 1 and ```N``` =4...Answer should be ```ans=2```(two pairs can be generated (A,B)=(4,0) or (A,B)=(3,1)) but your formula will give ```ans=8```.

Comment: Still trying to figure out

Answer (score -3):

Ok, sorry, I was (way) too fast.

You know there's always at least one solution.

You have to take at least enough fruit of A so that with B, it makes N. You take at max A fruit of A. If that's bigger than N, the limit is N. So the answer should be:

```
min(A, N) - max(0, N-B) + 1
```

Comment: No. Take for example total of 4 fruits. and you have 10 apples and 1 orange. The total number of combinations is 2. Either 1 orange and 3 apples or 0 oranges and 4 apples.

Comment: To explain a bit more: min(A,N) is the maximum number of A you can take. max(0, N-B) is the minimum number of A you need. The difference is hence always positive or 0 (because A + B >= N). The difference plus 1 is the thus the solution.